# How do I pay bills with AppendBillPaymentCheckAddReq?

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

How do I pay bills/create check with AppendBillPaymentCheckAddReq?

How do pay a bill that has been created using BillAddRq from my 3rd party app. I am not sure how to tell QB which bill to pay. I get the external ID from QB when creating the bill but not sure what to tell QB in order to pay a specific bill.

My 3rd party application is developed in .NET 4.x and c# as the language. I am referencing Interop.QBFC13.dll

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fill out the relevant information of the BillPaymentCheckAddRq, using some of the information from the Bill. The BillpaymentCheckAddRq object has a AppliedToTxnAddList object that will let you specify which transaction(s) you want to apply the check to.This is where you would specify the ID from the Bill.

`IAppliedToTxnAdd appliedTo = billPaymentCheckAdd.AppliedToTxnAddList.Append();
appliedTo.TxnID.SetValue(bill.TxnID.GetValue());
appliedTo.PaymentAmount.SetValue(paymentAmount);`

If you have more than one bill paid with a single check, you would keep appending `AppliedToTxnAdd` for each bill, along with the amount applied to each.